# How can I get the list of all active network interfaces programmatically?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport, ethernet

My objective is to determine the IP address for Ethernet on a device. But assuming that there are connections like WiFi and USB Ethernet, is there a particular way just to get the Ethernet IP ?

On a shell I would do `networksetup -listallhardwareports` which would give me a mapping of Hardware Port to Device. From that I would grep the device for Hardware Port: Ethernet and then use ifaddr struct to get my IP.

I know the ifaddr part, please suggest how to do the first part programmatically.
Also, is there an alternative approach ?

Comment: You can use the `scutil` command to list active network interface(s) with their IPv4&6 addresses:`scutil --nwi`

Answer (score 25):

There may be several different ways to accomplish what you're asking, however, I'll just throw this out there.

I have a MacBook Pro that doesn't have a built-in Ethernet Port so in my examples I'll use *Hardware Port: Wi-Fi* since I tested this in both examples below and it worked, however you can change it to *Hardware Port: Ethernet* if that is what the output of 
`networksetup -listallhardwareports` shows for you.

If you just want to output the target device's IP Address to `stdout`, use the following example:

```
$ ipconfig getifaddr $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Hardware Port: Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}')
192.168.1.100
```

If you want to assign it to a *variable* in a *script*, use the following example:

```
ipAddress="$(ipconfig getifaddr $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Hardware Port: Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}'))"
```

**Explanation:**

The relevant output of `networksetup -listallhardwareports` for my system is:

```
Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 28:cf:e3:10:a4:cd
```

*(Note: That is not my real MAC Address)*

Using `$(...)` command substitution in order to have something to pass to `ipconfig getifaddr <args>` I determine the Hardware Port's Device Name with the output of `networksetup -listallhardwareports` and pipe `|` it through `awk` which is looking for `Hardware Port: Wi-Fi` and uses the `get line` function, which reads the next line after the *match* and is passed to `print $2`, which in essence prints the second part of the line following the *match*, which in the case is `en0` and that gets passed to `ipconfig getifaddr` as its argument in the first example, e.g `ipconfig getifaddr en0`. The output of which is the IP Address.

In the second example a second `$(...)` command substitution is used around the complex command line used for the `stdout` example to assign it to the `ipAddress` *variable* when used in a *script*.

Note:  This is really meant to be an example as I've not coded it to account for the device being down.  In other words if the device doesn't have and IP Address there will be no output to `stdout` and nothing assigned to the `ipAddress` *variable* in the *script*.  Although in the *script* it can be coded to test whether or not the `ipAddress` *variable* is empty and act accordingly.

Comment: Oh thanks, but I am looking for a more syscall / C based solution....

Comment: if you know the name of the inteface you can use: ` ipconfig getifaddr en0`

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517090-scnetworkinterfacecopyall) to get a list of interfaces, then filter out the ones that don't return *Ethernet*
with [SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517371-scnetworkinterfacegetinterfacety?language=objc).
From there you can get the gateway and mask, etc - in python I use [netifaces](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces) for that.

Comment: Its is a best practice at AskDifferent to provide not just links, but important snippets from the pages you reference. All too often links die, and your answer becomes worthless without context. Feel free to copy & paste essential lines of code and background information so long as it is properly attributed.